# Convert instagram page addresses to usernames

Tags: php, rest, instagram-api

I have a web form, in this form my customers will put their Instagram page addresses, then I must export the username from the link
but I have a problem
people will put this addresses in some ways
for example:

```
https://instagram.com/username/
instagram.com/username/
https://instagram.com/username?igshare....
https://instagram.com/u/username
username
```

I am trying to found an api for this work
I send the link to the api, then it convert the link to username
Instagram hasn't this api, do you know which have this api?

Answer (score 0):

You could do without an API using the `parse_url()` and `substr()` functions to respectively extract "/username" out of "instagram.com/username" and removing the slash at the start, like so:

```
//assuming you pass the URL to another page using a POST request
$url = $_POST['url'];
$username = substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
```

Comment: but in a way, user will send this link `https://Instagram.com/u/username` how we can do for this way?

Comment: Then you can use regular expressions. Just replace the second line with `$username = preg_replace("/(\/u\/)|\//", "", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))`